# State in react is not rendering/displaying to the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm not able get what I'm doing wrong here. Could someone please help me out here. I'm unable to print the value to the screen. I'm trying to print the value from the state to the screen but I'm unable to.

Its not showing any error. I know this could be a silly mistake. Please help me out. Thanks

I'm not able get what I'm doing wrong here. Could someone please help me out here. I'm unable to print the value to the screen.  i'm trying to print the value from the state to the screen but i'm unable to.

Its not showing any error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Screen.css";

export default class Screen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roles: [
        { id: 1, value: "Contracts manager", isChecked: false },
        { id: 2, value: "In-house counsel", isChecked: false },
        { id: 3, value: "IT administrator", isChecked: false },
        { id: 4, value: "Law clerk", isChecked: false },
        { id: 5, value: "Legal administrator", isChecked: false },
        { id: 6, value: "Legal operations manager", isChecked: false },
        { id: 7, value: "Legal secretary", isChecked: false },
        { id: 8, value: "Paralegal", isChecked: false },
        { id: 9, value: "Procurement manager", isChecked: false },
        { id: 10, value: "Solicitor", isChecked: false },
        { id: 11, value: "Other", isChecked: false },
      ],
      aksha: "aksk",
    };
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  roleHandler = (event) => {
    let roles = this.state.roles;
    roles.forEach((role) => {
      if (role.value === event.target.value)
        role.isChecked = event.target.checked;
    });
    this.setState({ roles: roles });
  };
  render() {
    const newRoles = this.state.roles.map((role) => {
      return (
        <div className="border-inp">
          <label className="checkbox">
            <span className="checkbox__input">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="checkbox"
                key={this.state.roles.id}
                onClick={this.roleHandler}
                value={this.state.roles.value}
                checked={this.state.roles.checked}
              />{" "}
              {this.state.roles.value}
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Screenbg">
          <div id="viewport" className="screenview">
            <h3 className="wel">Welcome</h3>
            <div>
              <h5 className="role">What is your role?</h5>
              {newRoles}
            </div>
            <div className="grid-container btndiv">
              {/* <div className="grid-child purple">
                                <button className="btn">Back</button>
                            </div> */}
              <div className="grid-child green">
                {/* <Link to="/"> */}
                <button className="btn">Next</button>
                {/* </Link>  */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role` must be used for rendering your array. You were using state to get it.

```
render() {
    const newRoles = this.state.roles.map((role) => {
      return (
        <div className="border-inp">
          <label className="checkbox">
            <span className="checkbox__input">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="checkbox"
                key={this.state.roles.id}
                onClick={this.roleHandler}
                value={this.state.roles.value}
                checked={this.state.roles.checked}
              />
              {role.value}
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
```